# Parse a json search to show up in respective divs

Tags: php, json

I have a json output as

```
{"cities":[{"id":"1995","name":"Banahatti"},{"id":"5074","name":"Kolhapur(Maharashtra)"},{"id":"2356","name":"Sangola"},{"id":"906","name":"Shahada"},{"id":"536","name":"Puttur"}
```

This shows a list of sources for a bus ticketing application.The api returns me a response as json as shown above.

Now I wanted to show this json by extracting the ids and names and show this as a drop down menu.

```
<select><option value="1995">Banahatti</option>
<option value="2356">Sangola</option>
</select>
```

so

```
<select><?php echo "<option value=".$id.">".$name."</option>"?></select>
```

I wanted to loop through all ids and names and echo it as shown above.

Comment: Your JSON missing `]}` at last. check in http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: first need to correct your json data and then loop through you will get output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you posted incorrect json string over here (i.e missing of `]}` at end of json string) but you getting it right in actual. Than your code will be look something like this,

```
$data = json_decode($jsonString,true);
if(count($data['cities'])){
    echo "<select>";
    foreach($data['cities'] as $city){
      echo "<option value=".$city['id'].">".$city['name']."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/pvEUWb)**.

Answer (score -1):

```
$jsonData = json_decode($jsonString,true);

foreach($jsonData as $item){
   echo $item['id'].'<br />';
   echo $item['name'].'<br />';
}
```

WIll be work

Comment: Can someone tell my why give down vote ? If the answer is right ? He asking how can i "parse" json string...